# SLIME/SWANK crashes when my Common Lisp code syntax is slightly wrong

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, slime

If I omit a closing paren, or use the wrong string escape character, or think about Haskell, this happens:

1) Minibuffer error message

```
Lisp connection closed unexpectedly: connection broken by remote peer
```

2) SLIME stops working.

3) *inferior-lisp* error message:

```
*** - Lisp stack overflow. RESET
;; swank:close-connection: NIL
```

Restarting SLIME with M-x slime, then recompiling my code with C-c C-k creates the same error. So yes, I *have* tried turning it off and on again.

Specs:

Aquamacs 2.1 (Emacs 23.2)

Aquamacs SLIME

MacPorts CLISP 2.49

Mac OS X 10.6.4

MacBook Pro 5,1

Comment: Have you tried asking the SLIME list? The sign-up page is here: http://common-lisp.net/mailman/listinfo/slime-devel

Comment: Can you also paste the stack trace you would get by either including `(setq debug-on-error t)` or doing `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` before making the syntax error?  That will attract more attention as well as better answers.

Comment: Maybe you should stop thinking about Haskell ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using paredit I don't have these problems any more (at least the one with uneven number of parens)